# Setting value of Enterprise Keywords using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, client-object-model, enterprise-keywords

I have included the enterprise keywords column in my contenttype and list and I try to set the value using the managed CSOM. I just used the default already existing column so the column name is "TaxKeyword" and the hidden note field for that column is "TaxKeywordTaxHTField".

I tried to set the value like this:

```
item["TaxKeywordTaxHTField"] = "-1;#Test|6138f1b1-b85a-4149-b06f-f79f6069a33d";
```

This works completely fine for most types of files (aspx, txt, pdf) but doesn't work for all office file types (docx, xlsx, pptx). I don't get any error when I call the executequery method but the value is just not saved. When I update the value in the UI, everything is working fine.

How can I set the enterprise keywords value programatically for office documents  using managed CSOM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved the issue by setting the keywords in the following way:

```
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field entKeywordField = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Enterprise Keywords");
 TaxonomyField entKeywordFieldTaxonomy = ctx.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(entKeywordField);
 entKeywordFieldTaxonomy.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(item, new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(ctx, "-1;#Application|f897952a-107a-4988-9913-6d4094318ddb;#-1;#form|9f03d594-a4ef-443b-963d-1d05c3c85bd8", entKeywordField));
```

Answer (score 8):

The operation of setting `Enterprise Keywords` field value consists of two steps:

- first one to resolve Keyword in Managed Metadata service application
  (MMS), this what  `EnsureKeyword method` from below example is
  intended for
- After Keyword has been retrieved or created if it not existed, the
  value of Enterprise Keyword field is set to `TaxonomyFieldValueCollection`

The method `KeywordsManager.SetTaxKeywordValue` demonstrates how to set Enterprise Keywords field value:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy;

namespace SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Enterpise Keyword Manager
    /// </summary>
    public class KeywordsManager
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Set Enterprise Keyword Value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item">List Item</param>
        /// <param name="values">Keyword values</param>
        public static void SetTaxKeywordValue(ListItem item,string[] values)
        {
            var ctx = item.Context;
            var list = item.ParentList;
            var field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(TaxKeywordFieldName);
            var taxKeywordField = ctx.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
            ctx.Load(item,i=>i[TaxKeywordFieldName]);
            var keywords = values.Select(value => EnsureKeyword(taxKeywordField, value)).ToList();
            taxKeywordField.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(item, new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(ctx, GetTermsString(keywords), taxKeywordField));    
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Ensure Keyword 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="taxField"></param>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static Term EnsureKeyword(TaxonomyField taxField, string name)
        {
            var ctx = taxField.Context;
            var taxSession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(ctx);
            var termStore = taxSession.GetDefaultKeywordsTermStore();
            var keywords = termStore.KeywordsTermSet.GetAllTerms();
            var result = ctx.LoadQuery(keywords.Where(k => k.Name == name));
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            var keyword = result.FirstOrDefault();
            if (keyword != null)
            {
                return keyword;
            }
            keyword = termStore.KeywordsTermSet.CreateTerm(name, DefaultLanguage, Guid.NewGuid());
            ctx.Load(keyword);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            return keyword;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve formatted Term string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="term"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string GetTermString(Term term)
        {
            return string.Format("-1;#{0}{1}{2}", term.Name, TaxonomyGuidLabelDelimiter,term.Id);
        }

        private static string GetTermsString(IEnumerable<Term> terms)
        {
            var termsString = terms.Select(GetTermString).ToList();
            return string.Join(";#", termsString);
        }



        private const string TaxKeywordFieldName = "TaxKeyword";

        private const int DefaultLanguage = 1033;

        private const string TaxonomyGuidLabelDelimiter = "|";
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
    KeywordsManager.SetTaxKeywordValue(item,new []{"2013","2010"});
    item.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**Results**

[image]

[image]

For a more details please follow [Enterprise Keywords management in Office 365 via CSOM](http://blog.vgrem.com/2015/01/09/enterprise-keywords-management-in-office-365-via-csom/) post.